# Send location in background to socket in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, sockets, background-process

I have a App that send location of the a device and a web site can look this device imagine that it is like the option to share location in real time of whatsapp and I want to send the location when the app is in background for both android and iOS.

I had try use react-native-background-action but this library only work in iOS for more 30 seconds.

What you recommend me?

Comment: AFAIK what you wanna implement is just not possible.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/685525

Comment: You can do it. As long as you have "always" location permission and you have started location updates with background enabled then your app will receive periodic calls to `didUpdateLocations`. There is no need for any tasks or other tricks to keep your app running. Using react native will add some complexity; you need to find some framework that can pass the location updates from the native layer to your react native code